# Nextjs nested routing not found

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to create a nested route inside my nextjs project, but i'm receiving a 404 page not found when trying to request the page.

I have a route named `/dashboard/repository/blender` where `blender` is a dynamic name that the user can input and that works fine.

But the next step is then to create a subpage for that dynamic route which is named `tags`, and that's where I receive the 404. (`/dashboard/repository/blender/tags`)

Here's a screenshot of what i've tried to achieve the `tags` nested routing [image: Example]

Secondly I have also tried doing the following
[image: Example2]

What can I do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that structure please

```
dashboard (folder)
-repository (folder)
--[blender] (folder)
----tags.tsx (file)
```

example urls

/dashboard/repository/blender/tags

/dashboard/repository/surrender/tags

...

In your component, you can get it like below
tags.tsx

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const C = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { blender } = router.query;
  console.log(blender)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with

```
- /dashboard/repository/[repository]/index.js 
- /dashboard/repository/[repository]/tags.js
```